# Generate 'K' Nearest Neighbours to a datapoint

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I need to generate K nearest neighbours given a datapoint. I read up the [sklearn.neighbours module of sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#finding-the-nearest-neighbors) but it generates neighbours between two sets of data. What I want is probably a list of 100 datapoints closest to the datapoint passed.

Any KNN algorithm shall anyways be finding these K datapoints under the hood. Is there any way these K points could be returned as output?

Here is my [sample notebook](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/Shap/blob/master/Find%20Nearest%20Neighbours.ipynb).

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
```

This can give you the index of the k nearest neighbors in your dataset. use `kneighbors`, first value is the distance and second value is the index of the neighbors. From documentation:

```
>>> samples = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]]
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
>>> neigh.fit(samples) 
NearestNeighbors(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, ...)
>>> print(neigh.kneighbors([[1., 1., 1.]])) 
(array([[0.5]]), array([[2]]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to look under the hood.

Use the [kd-tree for nearest-neighbor lookup](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree). Once, you have the index ready, you would [query](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query) it for the k-NNs.

Ref example:

```
>>> from scipy import spatial
>>> x, y = np.mgrid[0:5, 2:8]
>>> tree = spatial.KDTree(list(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())))
>>> pts = np.array([[0, 0], [2.1, 2.9]])
>>> tree.query(pts)
(array([ 2.        ,  0.14142136]), array([ 0, 13]))
>>> tree.query(pts[0])
(2.0, 0)
```